# Initializr Bootstrap. Knowledgebase. How to create and edit content?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am in the process of creating a knowledgebase website for my office and I find [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/) pretty awesome. Now, people at work, which may not be HTML savvy, will be creating new articles and then posting them to this knowledge base.

Is there something you can recommend that would allow such type of user to create a document on somthing similar to Microsoft Word but web based and then publish?

Or do I have to write it from scratch?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Do you mean : http://ckeditor.com/ ?

Comment: Wow... Yeah. That pretty much rocks. Just a question. After someone creates a document in ckeditor, how do I save it as an html page? I mean, I'm using PHP and I know how to save files and all, I just wonder hot do I obtain the recently created html from CKEditor and insert it into a page or database.